# TextInputEditText outline colour is not visible before user clicks on it

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-layout

I'm trying to create Material Edittext with an outline border of color #666971, and my screen background and Edittext boxBackground color are the same #080909, so I can't see the Edittext outline all the time; it only appears when I click on it. Here's my code:

```xml
      <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    style="@style/DarkInputLayoutStyle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:hint="Goal name"
                    app:boxBackgroundMode="outline"
                    app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="0dp"
                    app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="0dp"
                    app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="0dp"
                    app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="0dp"
                    app:hintEnabled="true"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/title">
    
                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/raleway_regular"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:hint="E.g. House down payment, Paris trip"
                        android:inputType="text"
                        android:maxLength="50"
                        android:paddingStart="16dp"
                        android:paddingEnd="16dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/neutral_200"
                        android:textColorHint="@color/neutral_700"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_13sdp" />
    
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

> Theme.xml

```xml
     <style name="DarkInputLayoutStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
            <item name="boxStrokeWidth">2dp</item>
            <item name="boxStrokeColor">@color/neutral_700</item>
            <item name="boxBackgroundColor">@color/neutral_1000</item>
            <item name="hintTextColor">@color/neutral_700</item>
        </style>
```

> Note: My `boxBackgroundColor` and screen `background` color is same
> #080909

Answer (score 0):

Add `app:boxStrokeColor="#666971"` to your TextInputLayout. This will override any current outline color.

Comment: not work for me, I have already tried